# Rhino mock of inherited class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Im trying to mock System.Web.Mvc.ModelStateDictionary which does not have virtual methods. So I've tried to make a sub class in this way:

```
public abstract class ModelStateDictionaryMock : ModelStateDictionary
{
    public new abstract int Count { get; }

    public new abstract bool IsReadOnly { get; }

    public new abstract bool IsValid { get; }

    public new abstract ICollection<string> Keys { get; }

    public new abstract ICollection<ModelState> Values { get; }

    public new abstract ModelState this[string key] { get; set; }

    public new abstract void Add(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item);

    public new abstract void Add(string key, ModelState value);

    public new abstract void AddModelError(string key, Exception exception);

    public new abstract void AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);

    public new abstract void Clear();

    public new abstract bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item);

    public new abstract bool ContainsKey(string key);

    public new abstract void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>[] array, int arrayIndex);

    public new abstract IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> GetEnumerator();

    public new abstract bool IsValidField(string key);

    public new abstract void Merge(ModelStateDictionary dictionary);

    public new abstract bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, ModelState> item);

    public new abstract bool Remove(string key);

    public new abstract void SetModelValue(string key, ValueProviderResult value);

    public new abstract bool TryGetValue(string key, out ModelState value);
}
```

However when I generate a mock using `var modelStateDictionary = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ModelStateDictionaryMock>();` I get an object which has a double set of properties, like this:

[image: Watch 1]

Doing `modelStateDictionary.Count` accesses the base property, so my mock does not work. Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Because the properties are not overridden. You've just shadowed them using `new` keyword.

Comment: When you have the opportunity, you can consider using Microsoft Fakes (if you have the correct Visual Studio version).

Comment: @Complexity thanks. It works using MS Fakes. I'm doing `System.Web.Mvc.Fakes.ShimModelStateDictionary.AllInstances.AddModelErrorStringString =
                (dictionary, key, errorMessage) =>
                {
                    Assert.Fail(errorMessage);
                };`

Comment: Arrgh, all this mess because MS didnt do virtual or interface.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: you don't need to mock this class at all... just create a new instance of `ModelStateDictionary` and then use it in your UT...

Comment: @OldFox how can I then react to writes to that ModelStateDictionary?

Comment: @Drutten I don't understand your question.... you can use any method `ModelStateDictionary` has...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get double set of properties because you are defining the methods in your mock class as using the "new" keyword. This treats the method as a new method, and has nothing to do with the base method.

Also, because the base class method is not abstract or virtual, you really can't override it.

As for solving your mocking problem, normally there is no need to mock the `ModelState` dictionary.. once you have the controller reference, you get access to its `ModelState`, where you can setup the model errors etc. using the real object, and not mocking it.

Look at this post for details on how to setup errors on the Model State: [How to mock ModelState.IsValid using the Moq framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822873/how-to-mock-modelstate-isvalid-using-the-moq-framework)

Comment: I want to mock `ModelState` for two reasons:
  
1. To make sure that any errors added are actually failing the test. Otherwise I need to check `ModelState` after the test and that may be missed out.  
2. To get the failing line in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your mock in order to have it return a value.

> modelStateDictionary.Stub(x => x.Count).Return(10);

Now if you ask `modelStateDictionary.Count` it will return 10 instead of using the base implementation.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't.

Comment: Can you show some more code then. Copied your class and wrote this little test that seems to work.

`var modelStateDictionary = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ModelStateDictionaryMock>();
modelStateDictionary.Stub(x => x.Count).Return(10);
Assert.That(modelStateDictionary.Count, Is.EqualTo(10));`

Comment: Try `(modelStateDictionary as ModelStateDictionary).Count`. It returns 0.

Comment: Why do you need to perform a cast?

Comment: It is implicitly casted since the type of `ModelState` is `ModelStateDictionary`