# Stub for ModelState.IsValid in ASP.NET MVC using RhinoMock

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rhino-mocks

I want to stub `ModelState.IsValid`, so I'm using following construction:

```
SomeController controller = MockRepository.GenerateStub<SomeController>();
controller.Stub(x => x.ModelState.IsValid).Return(false);
```

After invoke, I get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid call, the last call has been used or no call has been made (make sure that you are calling a virtual (C#) / Overridable (VB) method).
```

Why this exception is thrown and how the `ModelState.IsValid` can be stubbed ? Do I have to do something like this: `controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", "")` for invalidating model state ?

Regards

Answer (score 3):

For testing validation, I usually pass the action a model which fails validation, similar to Scott Hanselman's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286124/how-can-i-test-modelstate/589350#589350).

If that's not an option then use `controller.ModelState.AddModelError("", "")`.